# Filter in Userform, ComboBox show only filtered data

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with ComboBoxes and filter, when I set filter from ComboBox1 ("Today" or "This Week") and press the button, I want to ComboBox2 show only filtered data which is in column 1, How to do this? This is my code:

`Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()`

`Dim rng As Range 
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("Database")

If ComboBox1.Value = "Today" Then
    With rng
     .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
      xlFilterToday, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
    End With
End If
If ComboBox1.Value = "This Week" Then
    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
        xlFilterThisWeek, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
    End With
End If
End Sub`